# Trying to seperate a cell by letters followed by numbers

Tags: excel, formula

I have a few data sets that need to be separated in Excel. However I am unable to separate it how I need it. The cells have a few different setups.

They will always start with a Letter T,L,R,B and continue with at least 1 digit up to 3 Sometimes containing an M. A few types are `T01B03`, `T001` and `R011L15M`.

I'm trying to separate them by the T,L,R,B. The `R011L15M` would need to be in 2 cells `[R011]` `[L15M]`

Couldn't find any formulas besides using MID but I couldn't get the Code to separate by multiple values.

Thank you,

Comment: Is there any limit to how many times T, L, R, or B can show up in a certain string?

Comment: Just 1, 1 of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE to create large groups of spaces.  Then with MID and some MATH we separate the text and trim off the excess spaces:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"T",REPT(" ",99)&"T"),"L",REPT(" ",99)&"L"),"B",REPT(" ",99)&"B"),"R",REPT(" ",99)&"R"),(COLUMN(A:A))*99+1,99))
```

Copy over and down.

[image]